Ising Model magnetisation
I am simulating the 2D Ising Model and specifically looking at the time evolution of magnetisation $m$. Now, in the non-equilibrium state, magnetisation will grow as a power law with time $t$, if started from an initial random configuration of spins for the Metropolis algorithm.
Will there be any system size dependence for this non-equilibrium dynamics because in the log-log plot of magnetisation vs. time, I am getting the slope of the linear curve obtained to be dependent on lattice size (slope increases with increase in system size).
If so, can anyone help me to have a rough estimate of how this will scale as N? where N is the linear lattice dimension.
Specifically I am asking that if $m \sim f(N) t^c $, does anyone know about a rough estimate of $f$?

Reminds me of aging. You can look into "A Crash Course on Aging"

Shouldn't the magnetization be between 0 and N.me? Your mesh dependent polynomial time increase looks like a numerical artefact.

No, actually I am considering the absolute value of magnetisation per spin, so |m| essentially lies between 0 and 1. And also I am considering zero temperature dynamics, starting my simulation with an initial configuration of random spins. And the time is in units of Mone-Carlo steps.
